# Projecting out known augemented reality marker positions from any found marker

Tags: c#, math, xna, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I have a set of square markers indexed from 0-5. These markers are represented by an offset from its parent and a set of rotations (x,y,z). The parent is another marker (0-5). For instance, I can have marker 0 being the root marker, 1 being a child of 0 with offset (x:10,y:0,z:5) and rotation (x:0.5,y:0.1,z:0), 2 being a child of 1, 3 being a child of 0 and so on.

To find the relative 3D position of a marker from the base marker you simply chain the transform matrices formed from the offsets and rotations.

The 2nd step of the process is to detect these markers from a camera view. I have done this using ALVAR marker tracker which is similar to ARToolkit. I am using a wrapper that will allow me to access the camera transform matrix for each detected marker in XNA matrix format (this is corrected from OpenGL format via the wrapper).

I want to test how accurate the detected marker model matches my defined model. To do this I am choosing one of the detected markers as a 'base' marker and reprojected out the defined marker model from this.

Using XNA the code is this:

First we find the relative transform of the 'base' marker from the 0 (root) marker:

```
Matrix globalTransformToPerform=Matrix.Identity;

//Find the markerIDTOBAse on
int mibo = 0;
foreach (Bone b in model.bones)
{
   foreach (Marker m in b.markers)
   {
       if (mibo != markerIDToBaseOn)
       {
           mibo++;
           continue;
        }
        else
        {
           //Chain Marker transform
           Matrix markerTransform =
                             Matrix.CreateRotationZ(m.z) *
                             Matrix.CreateRotationX(m.x) *
                             Matrix.CreateRotationY(m.y) *
                             Matrix.CreateTranslation(m.offset);

            //Add bone transform
            markerTransform *= Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(b.z)) *
                             Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(b.x)) *
                             Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(b.y)) *
                             Matrix.CreateTranslation(b.Offset);

            //Chain parents transforms
            Bone parent = b.parent;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                 Matrix parentLocalTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(parent.z)) *
                                               Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(parent.x)) *
                                               Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(parent.y)) *
                                               Matrix.CreateTranslation(parent.Offset);

                 markerTransform *= parentLocalTransform;

                 parent = parent.parent;
            }
                 globalTransformToPerform = markerTransform;
                 mibo++;
          }
       }
 }
```

Now for each corner of each marker, we find the expected 2D projected position of it on the screen based on the 'base' marker.

```
 foreach (Bone b in model.bones)
 {
    foreach (Marker m in b.markers)
    {
        //foreach of the corners...
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            Matrix cornerTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Global.cornerModel[i]);

            //Chain Marker transform
             Matrix markerTransform = cornerTransform *
                                      Matrix.CreateRotationZ(m.z) *
                                      Matrix.CreateRotationX(m.x) *
                                      Matrix.CreateRotationY(m.y) *
                                      Matrix.CreateTranslation(m.offset);

            //Add bone transform
            markerTransform *= Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(b.z)) *
                               Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(b.x)) *
                               Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(b.y)) *
                               Matrix.CreateTranslation(b.Offset);

            //Chain parents transforms
            Bone parent = b.parent;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                  Matrix parentLocalTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(parent.z))*        Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(parent.x))     *
                                                Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(parent.y)) *
                                                Matrix.CreateTranslation(parent.Offset);

                   markerTransform *= parentLocalTransform;

                   parent = parent.parent;
             }

             //Find 3D position
             Vector3 location = (markerTransform).Translation;

             //Now project
             Vector3 v = viewPort.Project(location * scalingFactor, projectionMatrix, Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 3), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up), worldTransform*globalTransformToPerform);
              Vector2 res = new Vector2(v.X, v.Y);

              //Store result
              cornersToRet.Add(res);
         }

      }
  }
```

The problem is, the markers do no show up as expected. Things I have tried:

- The wrapper works correctly, this has been tested
- The model is correct, I have drawn this to the screen using XNA and it is as expected.
- I drew the model to the screen using the same transforms as the above code.

This is what happens when I run it:

Green is the markers detected by the marker tracker projected onto the screen.
Red is the marker corners from the model based on the 'base' marker.

The model is below:
[image]

The experiments:
1. 0 is base marker, this one works because transformation from the base is the same

[image]

2. 1 is the base marker. This is incorrect.

Any help with solving this would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot.. but according to what I read in your explanation you 1st detect the marker #1 and then marker #2 and so on... I Assume that if you failed to identify a marker along the way you invalidate the previous marker as well. in reality paper -> marker #1 cannot be identified correctly becuase the next marker #2 is not to the right of marker #1 so both are invalidated.
As I said this is a long shot but.. how about you try to rotate your paper 90deg clockwise?